# Kendo Mobile vs jQuery Mobile design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, kendo-mobile

From what I can tell, one of the main differences between Kendo Mobile and jQuery Mobile is that Kendo uses a single index page that loads the entire DOM of every page you are ever going to use at the initial load.  This makes moving from page to page very fast, but it seems like a LOT of rending of pages that will rarely be used.

jQuery mobile only loads the page when it's actually visited.  It makes the responsiveness a bit slower, but keeps the DOM a bit cleaner.  It seems to work a lot better with native ASP.Net MVC, because you can actually call the controller and render the view, where this doesn't seem possible in Kendo.

Have I gotten the underlying basics correct here, or is there a big piece I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great article that I found:

http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-11-14/jquery-mobile-and-kendo-ui-mobile---a-dom-omparison

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell - Kendo will allow for a better Native feel without the need for a graphic designer. The styling is just that much better IMHO - Kendo also offers the MVVM framework and allows for templating right out of the box.

As well, if you run AppBuilder - the seamless cloud support is another advantage. Kendo also runs much more smoothly on iOS due to your first point and is FASTER overall in rendering and Cordoba interactions.